# Testing a function which consumes promises

Tags: node.js, testing, jasmine, promise, bluebird

I've got a MEAN app and I'm trying to get tests to work on the node side. Async events are wrapped in promises, which are consumed in the controller. I failed at testing the controller :(

The controller I'm trying to test:

```
ProjectController.prototype.getAll = function(req, res, next) {
  req.dic.subjectRepository
  .getById(req.params.subjectId)
  .then(function(subject) {
    res.json(subject.projects);
  }, function(err) {
    return res.status(404).send('Subject does not exist.' + err);
  });
};
```

The `subjectRepository` is our data source, which returns a promise (`mpromise` because under the hood we're using `mongoose`, but it shouldn't matter):

So in our test we tried mocking the request (we're injecting our dependency injection container from a middleware into the `req`) and response (the test succeeds if `response.json()` has been called with the subjects we tried to fetch) and our subjectRepository. We used `bluebird` (although I tried others out of frustration) to create fake promises for our mocked `subjectRepository`:

```
describe('SubjectController', function() {

  'use strict';

  var Promise = require('bluebird');

  it('gets all existing subjects', function() {

    // -------------------------------------
    // subjectRepository Mock
    var subjectRepository = {
      getAll: function() {},
    };
    var subjectPromise = Promise.resolve([
      {name: 'test'},
      {name: 'test2'},
    ]);
    spyOn(subjectRepository, 'getAll').andReturn(subjectPromise);

    // -------------------------------------
    // request mock
    var req = {
      dic: {
        subjectRepository: subjectRepository,
      },
    };

    // -------------------------------------
    // response mock
    var res = {
      json: function() {},
      send: function() {},
    };
    spyOn(res, 'json');

    // -------------------------------------
    // actual test
    var subjectController = new (require('../../../private/controllers/SubjectController'))();
    subjectController.getAll(req, res);

    // this succeeds
    expect(subjectRepository.getAll).toHaveBeenCalled();

    // this fails
    // expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**Question: How do I make the test run the `expect()` AFTER the promise succeeded?**

Node v0.12

The code is on GitHub for anyone who's interested: https://github.com/mihaeu/fair-projects

And maybe I should mention that the controller is called from the router:

```
// router handles only routing
// and controller handles data between view and model (=MVC)
subjectRouter.get('/:subjectId', subjectController.get);
```

I got this to work by changing our controllers to hand down the promises, but I'm not sure this is what we want. Isn't there a way to get my approach to work?

```
  it('gets all existing subjects', function(done) {    

      // ...

    var subjectController = new (require('../../../private/controllers/SubjectController'))();
    subjectController.getAll(req, res).then(function() {
      expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testSubjects);    // success
    }).finally(done);
    expect(subjectRepository.getAll).toHaveBeenCalled();    // success
  }
```

Comment: Very difficult, as your `getAll` method doesn't return a promise. If it did (like in your update), it should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes the mistake of mixing business logic with front facing routing.

If your getAll did *not* touch the request and response object, it would look something like this:

```
ProjectController.prototype.getAll = function(subjectId) {
  return req.dic.subjectRepository.getById(subjectId).then(function(subject){
    return subject.projects;
  });
};
```

Now, it is no longer related to the request response life cycle or in charge of logic, testing it is trivial by:

```
it("does foo", function(){
  // resolve to pass the test, reject otherwise, mocha or jasmine-as-promised
  return controller.getAll(152).then(...) 
});
```

That would make your *actual* handler look like:

```
 app.get("/projects", function(req, res){
    controller.getAll(req.params.subjectId).then(function(result){
       res.json(result); 
    }, function(){
       res.status(404).send("...");
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Benjamin. That way you've made the Controller a Model and it simply hands down the exact same promise.

My next question would be how to test the callback in the route.

In MVC a controller's job is to act as a "controller" between the view and the model.

    // our router injects the repository into the controller and the controller
    // is the extracted callback you posted (callbacks are just harder to test 
    // and routing will be mixed with control logic)
    subjectRouter.get('/', subjectController.getAll);